# NIntegrate::slwcon, NIntegrate::eincr and Set::wrsym problems

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have the following piece of code where I try to compute the triple integral.

```
 wzeq = 2.5021
 Omeg = 1.5
 GG = 2.1
 alpha = 3.9478
 sigma = Sqrt[0.3]
 nu = Sqrt[sigma^2 Abs[Omeg^2 - 0.25 GG^2]]
 sigmaR = Sqrt[0.1]
 A0 = 0.0032
 mu = -sigmaR^2/2
 h0 = 0.001
 NIntegrate[z/(h0^2 x^2 Sqrt[Log[A0 x/h0]]) Exp[-wzeq^2/(4 sigma^2) Log[
  A0 x/h0] -  1/2 ((Log[x] + sigmaR^2/2)/sigmaR)^2] Exp[-1/(2 alpha) (y/(sigmaR x))^2 - wzeq^2 (z/h0 - y/x)^2/(16 nu^2 Log[A0 x/h0])], {z, 0, ,Infinity}, {x, h0/A0, h0/A0, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

However, I keep getting warning messages.

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.011684038916126538 `and 2.9472154143362325`*^-8 for the integral and error estimates.

Is there a way to fix this issue as I suspect that the value of the integral is not correct.

Comment: What is the intermediate point in the z-range? It is missing. The numerical integration computation converges, but it seems you will get different results using, say, these options `MinRecursion -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 8, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 20000}`.

Comment: What do you mean by  the intermediate point in the z-range?

Answer (score 1):

```
                 wzeq = 2.5021; Omeg = 1.5; GG = 2.1; alpha = 3.9478;
         sigma = Sqrt[0.3]; nu = 
        Sqrt[sigma^2*Abs[(Omeg^2 - 0.25*GG^2)]]; sigmaR = 
       Sqrt[0.1]; A0 = 0.0032; mu = (sigmaR^2)/2; h0 = 0.001;
       Quiet[NIntegrate[
      z/(h0^2*x^2 Sqrt[Log[A0*x/h0]])*
      Exp[-((wzeq^2*Log[A0 x/h0])/(4 sigma^2)) - 
      1/2*((Log[x] - mu)/sigmaR)^2]*
       Exp[-1/(2 alpha) (y/(sigmaR*x))^2 - (
      wzeq^2*(z/.004206515 - y/x)^2)/(16 nu^2 *Log[A0 x/h0])], {z, 0, 
     Infinity}, {x, h0/A0, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 10, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]]                      (*outputs*) 
            (*0.0735043*)
```

Comment: I have an idea on the value of the result, it should be around 0.032 with the parameters mentioned in my post. I don't understand how you got this very small value. Also, I think "Quiet" will stop the messages from being displayed but it won't solve them.

Comment: In your code there is typo in limit of x, and you can not use "I as you have used"  because it is assigne for imaginary number. You can find this  result without using  "Quiet" ,

Comment: To which line you are referring to? this one {x, h0/A0, Infinity}?

Comment: yes, check your uploded code

Comment: Actually, I did that on purpose since I suspect that $h0/A0$ is a singularity point. According to the Mathematica documentation, it should give more accurate result when you precise the singularity. You were talking about imaginary number. Could you kindly edit your post with your solution, it is easier to understand in this case. Thanks.

Comment: I always found very small number ( order of 10^-150) without  any error.  I think you have to check your parameters for desired result.

Comment: I'm using the same parameters with another method and I'm getting a value around 0.032. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Good, It seem that bracket is not in order. Bacause right now you can see in edited code output (10^-51). Can you provide the snaps of equation.

Comment: I've updated the post with the equation. Thanks.

Comment: You have to  confirm the term containg (z/h-y/x) in code you have used h0 but in image simply h. Solution strongly dépends on value of h. I have choose (updeted code) some value that give .073 very close to your expected value (.032).

Comment: Actually, you are right. It is $h_0$ not $h$. I've updated the post.

Comment: Also, for the value of $\mu$, there is a minus sign missing.